# Endomorphism on $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering about an endomorphism.
If we have an endomorphism $f$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ such as its matrix in canonical basis is

\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 0 \\
   -1 & 2 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

and $V=Vect{(1,1,1)}$, $Z=Vect((1,0,0),(0,1,-1))$

We see $V$  is invariant by $f$ and $Z$ is invariant by $f$

We compute the characteristic polynomial which is $-x^3+4 x^2-6 x+4$ and the eigenvalues are $2,(1+i),(1-i)$

Then $f$ is diagonalizable on $\mathbb{C^3}$ but not on  $\mathbb{R^3}$

I would like to find a basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$ in which the matrix f looks like 
\begin{pmatrix}
   * & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & * & * \\
   0 & * & * \\
\end{pmatrix}

With triangularization I find the basis

\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & (1-i) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & (1+i) \\
\end{pmatrix}

but it's on $\mathbb{C^3}$ how could we do on $\mathbb{R^3}$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You know that the span of $(1,1,1)$ is contributes for the upper left portion of your $\begin{pmatrix}
   * & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & * & * \\
   0 & * & * \\
\end{pmatrix}$. For the lower right block you should look to compute the orthogonal space $\text{span}\{(1,1,1)\}^\perp$.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have never seen this way of doing how could we compute the orthogonal space ?

Comment: Given that the vector you started with is so simple, it is easy to spot by eye that $(1,-1,0), (1,0,-1)$ are independent and both orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$. Please notice that you may also want to convert your original matrix to standard basis in order to see that this orthogonal space is actually invariant. If you don't feel like converting to standard basis, then you will have to express the orthogonal basis vectors I have provided in terms of the original basis you were working with.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** The $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ blocks correspond to a one-dimensional and a two-dimensional invariant subspaces. You are given such spaces (including bases).